# Powershell. Run Command for Every Specific String in Array

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionConfig -ResourceGroupName RG1 -Name CoolTestWebApp1 | Select -ExpandProperty MainSiteAccessRestrictions
```

That once is ran outputs array:

```
RuleName    : IP-1
Description : 
Action      : Allow
Priority    : 1
IpAddress   : 10.0.0.0/24
SubnetId    : 

RuleName    : IP-2
Description : 
Action      : Allow
Priority    : 2
IpAddress   : 10.0.0.1/24
SubnetId    :
```

How can I run a command for every entry in `RuleName`?
For example, something like:

```
Get-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionConfig -ResourceGroupName RG1 -Name CoolTestWebApp1 | Select -ExpandProperty MainSiteAccessRestrictions | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $RuleNameX }
```

That would execute:

```
Write-Host $RuleName1
Write-Host $RuleName2
```

Which in turn would output:

```
IP-1
IP-2
```

Comment: you seem to have answered your question. [*grin*] the `Write-Host` is a command ... and you are running it once per item ... so replace the `Write-Host` with all the commands you want to run. [*grin*]

Comment: I don't want to run a command for every entry in object. I want to run a command for every value in `RuleName`, while passing that value to another command.

Comment: it looks like `retryW` has shown the specifics of how to get the 2nd level of objects. it's the same concept as how you got the 1st ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much had it:

```bsh
Get-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionConfig -ResourceGroupName RG1 -Name CoolTestWebApp1 | Select -ExpandProperty MainSiteAccessRestrictions | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.RuleName }
```

Within a `ForEach-Object`, you can access the current objects attributes using `$_.`

i.e

```bsh
ForEach-Object { $_.attributeName }
```

---

If the `RuleName` attribute contains an array of values, you could then iterate over them too:

```bsh
$siteRestrictions = (Get-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionConfig -ResourceGroupName RG1 -Name CoolTestWebApp1).MainSiteAccessRestrictions

# Loop through objects
foreach($item in $siteRestrictions) {
  # Loop through each RuleName
  foreach($ruleName in $item.RuleName) {
    # Do some logic here
  }
}
```